# displaying alternate rows of one particular column to two different column

Tags: rows

I have one table  having field Empid,RecTime,EmpId ,Recdate.

Here is the code:
 s = "Select e.EmpName,a.EmpId,a.WorkID,a.RecDate,a.RecTime from HrEmployee e,AtdRecord a where a.EmpId=e.EmpId and  EmpName='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and RecDate between '" & TextBox2.Text & "' and '" & TextBox3.Text & "'"

```
    cmd = New SqlCommand(s, conn)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(s, conn)
    'ds = New DataSet 'da.Fill(ds)
    dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    dc1 = New DataColumn("InTime")  ' make column InTime and OutTime
    dc2 = New DataColumn("OutTime")
    dt.Columns.Add(dc1)
    dt.Columns.Add(dc2)
    'For entering data from database col to datatable (Intime,Outtime)
    For Each dr In dt.Rows
        i = 4
        mystring = dr(i)

        timestring = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr)
        If timestring Mod 2 = 0 Then

            j = 5

            dr(j) = mystring
        Else
            k = 6
            dr("OutTime") = mystring
        End If
    Next

    For Each col In dt.Columns
        bfield = New BoundField
        bfield.DataField = col.ColumnName
        bfield.HeaderText = col.ColumnName
        'GridView1.Columns.Add(bfield)
    Next
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
    conn.Close()
```

I want to know how can i get the values in this scenario from RecTime:

```
InTime    Outtime    
8             9
1:30          2:45
```

When RecTime:

```
    8
    9
    1:30
    2:45
```